# Why multiple GPU are getting used even though I choose one from terminal?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I have a server access which has multiple GPUs that can be accessed simultaneously by many users.
I choose only 1 gpu_id from the terminal and have a code like this.

```
device = "cuda:"+str(FLAGS.gpu_id) if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
```

where `FLAGS` is a parser, parsing arguments from terminal.

Even though I select only one id, I saw that I am using 2 different GPUs. That causes issues, when the other GPU memory is almost full, and my process terminates by throwing "CUDA out of memory" error.

I want to understand, what could be the possible cases for such thing to happen?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what is wrong without knowing how you use the device parameter. In any case, you can try to achieve what you want with a different approach. Run your python script in the following way:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python3 my_code.py
```